# Where do Loki and the Space Stone end up?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*,

> in past tense after Battle of New York (Avengers 1) and Loki is held in custody, the plan to (borrow) steal the Space Stone goes awry and Loki grabs it and disappears.

Do we find out where Loki ends up with the Space Stone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

##### They end up at the Time Variance Authority's (TVA) headquarters.

The TV series *[Loki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loki_(TV_series))* (2021) reveals what happened to the Loki who escaped with the Space Stone in *Avengers: Endgame*. He was captured by the Time Variance Authority (TVA), an organization that oversees the main timeline, or the “sacred timeline”, as they call it. Loki and the Space Stone ended up in a realm beyond normal space and time, where the TVA operates. He was considered a variant who unwittingly created a divergent branch in the sacred timeline by escaping with the Space Stone. The TVA then enlisted his help to fix the timeline anomalies.

Answer (score 4):

It's unknown yet.

However, we can see Loki is still at Asgard's prison when we see Thor breaking into the fort. Therefore, it is possible Thor or someone manages to capture Loki and put him into the prison. But where Loki went or how this happens is unclear as there are no official words about his whereabouts.

It is possible that it may get explained in TV series made for him, but we're not sure of it yet either.

Comment: That's a bit I don't get, the stones are back, but certain people who turn up at the end of the movie, from a different timeline aren't back. Surely that's already created a paradox?

Comment: There is no confirmation about it. All we know at the moment is what Ancient One said.

Comment: Stark retrieves the Space Stone from the lab, but the problem is the one Loki takes is definitely out of place/time/space.

Comment: @enorl76 But Captain America has returned them all to their original place.

Comment: The ancient one didn't say anything about keeping the same timeline, she just says that her branch of reality is doomed if not all infinity stones exist in it. Therefore they must return the stones but not necessarily without altering the timeline. In the end we have many more timelines, because the Avengers travelled to different years and changed things dramatically.

Comment: @AJ Captain American returned the CA:TFA space stone to its original time but what about space stone from Avengers which loki steal?

Comment: @AnkitSharma I missed that somehow. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Christopher Markus  answered it to [Fandango](https://www.fandango.com/movie-news/exclusive-interview-the-avengers-endgame-writers-break-down-the-biggest-moments-in-the-movie-spoilers-753736?cjid=cj_10369448_8519045_100652X1574804X73c73b54ecf5b15563df9249a5f28527&cjevent=8d368bd7704011e98348002d0a180512):

> **Fandango: The Snap did bring back a lot of our favorite characters. Loki, is he kicking around somewhere? And what about Vision?**
>
> **Christopher Markus:** No, I mean we only brought back the people who were effectively disintegrated by the Snap at the end of Infinity War. Anybody who died over the course of the movie through neck-snapping or stabbing or being thrown off a cliff or having a Mind Stone torn out of their head stayed dead.

But Russo and Anthony contradict it, from [Business Insider](https://www.businessinsider.in/Avengers-Endgame-directors-describe-the-pressure-and-grueling-work-of-concluding-this-phase-of-the-Marvel-Cinematic-Universe-and-tease-whats-in-store-for-the-future/articleshow/69206493.cms):

> **Clark: At the end, when Cap brings the stones back in time, does he correct all the timelines that got screwed up? Is there a past Loki
> still out there?**
>
> **Joe:** The intent was that he was going to correct the past timelines at the point that the stones left.
>
> Loki, when he teleports away with the Time Stone, would create his own
> timeline. It gets very complicated, but it would be impossible for
> [Cap] to rectify the timeline unless he found Loki. The minute that
> Loki does something as dramatic as take the Space Stone, he creates a
> branched reality.
>
> **Anthony:** We're dealing with this idea of multiverses and branched realities, so there are many realities.

But I will probably go with Russo as Loki is going to appear in his own TV series soon on [Disney+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disney%2B) as user5603 said in her answer.  But we need to wait and watch how it's going to happen.

Answer (score 2):

Loki ends up starring in a Disney TV/Streaming series involving lots of jumping through space with the space stone.

His action of stealing the Tesseract from the end of Avengers doesn't actually break the timeline if you assume that the Tesseract is returned to the end of the Avengers in time for Thor/Loki to return to Asgard.

Comment: It is true that a Loki TV show is in production, but is it official that it will involve the Space Stone?